# Proving that the winding number is $k$

Tags: complex-analysis, winding-number

I am trying to prove that the winding number $n(p\circ\gamma_r,0)$ is $k$, when $p(z)=a\prod_{j=1}^k(z-z_j)$ is a complex polynomial of degree $k$ and $\gamma_r:[0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, \gamma_r(t)=re^{it} $. For $r$ we assume $r > max_{j=1, \dots, k} |z_j|$.

So far I have tried to compute
$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{p\circ\gamma_r}\frac{dw}{w} $ and arrived after some calculations at $$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{p\circ\gamma_r}\frac{dw}{w}=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{f'_1}{f_1}(t)+\dotsi+\frac{f'_k}{f_k}(t)dt$$ where $f_j= re^{it}-z_j$ and $f'_j=ire^{it}$. However, I could not produce any idea how to evaluate the antiderivatives of the quotients $\frac{f'_j}{f_j}(t)$. Or am I on the wrong path anyway? Any hint would be highly appreciated.

In the comments I learned that the residue theorem and some properties of homotopy of closed curves are very helpful here, but unfortunately, neither of these topics has been subject of our lectures yet. So I would be very greatful if someone could give me a hint on how to proceed without these theorems.

Comment: residue theorem is very helpful in this case. It easily allows us to conclude the integral is equal to $k\cdot 2\pi i$. Anyway, even if you haven't proven the resiude theorem itself, the actual proof of the residue theorem itself is useful here, and it is simple enough, provided you know about homotopy of closed curves and how this doesn't affect the value of the integral

Comment: Do you care to use the Argument principle? Or you intend for a direct computation instead?

Comment: Thank you for the hint! Unfortunately, we do not have this theorem in our lecture yet, so there should be another way.

Comment: another approach is  to notice that $p\circ \gamma_r$ is homotopic to $q \circ \gamma$ with $q(z) = z^k$. Since the winding number is invariant under homotopy, this makes it easier to compute

Comment: I have also heard about the argument principle, but it hasn't been subject of our lecture yet, either. So I assume, direct computation is what I opt for.

Comment: Thank you @SolubleFish, that made the computation so much easier! Unfortunately, we didn't have homotopy either in our lecture, so I'm not quite sure whether the lecturer intended another way for us to compute it.